# Wrong NuGet package version is getting generated

Tags: c#, debugging, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a nuget project several projects depend on and I need to add a new feature. Before I made any changes I pulled down all the code and was able to debug inside my nuget packages from a project references the nuget packages using this tutorial: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/29/debugging-nuget-package/

After I made the changes, however, is where the problems began and I am unable to debug. There are three nuget projects all in the same solution: Project1, Project2, and Project3. Project1 references Project2 and Project2 references Project3. Due to them just being a project reference to each other, for my purpose in my base project I only need to install the nuget package for Project1.

Locally, I have updated all the packages and their versions and pushed to create beta packages. If I update my source project to use the most recent beta nuget package for Project1, it works fine and I can reference the new fields in models in Project3. When I try to pull in the locally-built dlls however (which are the exact same code as what's on the server), Project3 is no longer referenced correctly. It is 1.4 on the server and locally, but when I use the Jetbrains Decompiler after adding a reference to the local dll, it says it is version 1.3 and has none of the changes that I made and the project breaks. How do I get it to generate the correct assembly version locally?

Comment: As you described, project 1referenced project 2, project 2 referenced project 3 and if you want project 1 to use the nuget package, you should install the nuget package in project 3. I'm not sure if it's a statement problem. Besides, since you have test the beta package several times, please try to [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) first.

Comment: Perhaps, if  the name of new package is the same as the old. It will install the old same package under the nuget cache first. In addition, please describe this problem more clearly so that we can locate the problem more quickly